# UUID generated using two programming languages?

Tags: java, ruby, guid, uuid

Will the UUID generated using two programming languages say 'Ruby' and 'Java' be unique?

Comment: I bet you mean UUID and the answer is, there are 100 - epsilon % chances that they will be unique, with epsilon very, very close to 0

Comment: yes,I was mentioning UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. UUID is a standard format - the formatting will be the same in any language that accurately implements a UUID function. As for the IDs themselves being unique? You have a much better chance of being struck by lightning while being attacked by a shark, after your second plane crash of the day, after winning the lottery a few times in a row, than generating two identical UUIDs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes a UUID (universally unique identifier) will be unique.

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

> only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100
>   years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about
>   50%. Or, to put it another way, the probability of one duplicate would
>   be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.